# Does multiple inheritance order matters?

Tags: c++, casting, mi

I have come up with some confusing situations. Below are they.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
    Base(int num) : data(num) {
        cout << "BASE : " << num << endl;
    }
    virtual ~Base() = default;

    virtual void func1() {
        cout << "Base func1 called : " << data << endl;
    }

    virtual void func3() {
        cout << "Base func3 called : " << data << endl;
    }

private:
    int data;
};

class Interface {
public:
    Interface() {
        cout << "INTERFACE : " << endl;
    }
    virtual ~Interface() = default;

    virtual void func2() {
        cout << "Interface func2 called" << endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Interface, public Base {
public:
    Derived() : Base(0) {
        cout << "DERIVED : hh" << endl;
    }
    virtual ~Derived() = default;

    virtual void func1() override {
        cout << "Derived fuc1 called" << endl;
    }

    virtual void func3() override {
        cout << "Derived fuc3 called" << endl;
    }

    virtual void func2() override {
        cout << "Derived fuc2 called" << endl;
    }


};

int main() {
    //Interface* a = new Derived(); // derived func2 called
    //Base* a = new Derived();    // derived func1 called
    //Derived* a = new Derived(); // derived func2 called
    void* a = new Derived();      // derived func1 called
    auto b = (Interface*)a;
    b->func2();
    
    ...
}
```

When executing `b->func2()`, the result is different by the explicit type of variable a.

The results are in the comments.

Why are they different when executing `b->func2()`?

Answer (score 3):

```
void* a = new Derived();      // derived func1 called
auto b = (Interface*)a;
```

This is undefined behavior. The usual semantics of converting a pointer to a derived class to a pointer to its base class apply only, well, when you convert a pointer to a derived class into a pointer to its base class. But that's not what happens here.

An intermediate conversion into some other pointer, like a `void *` voids all warranty (pun not intended).

Comment: There is one warranty: you can cast the `void*` back to its original type, i.e., `Derived*`.

Answer (score 3):

```cpp
void* a = new Derived();
auto b = (Interface*)a;
```

This is **Undefined Behavior**.  You are not casting the `void*` back to the same type that was stored in it (`Derived*`).

If you want to cast the `void*` to `Interface*` then you need to store an `Interface*` in the `void*` to begin with, eg:

```cpp
void* a = static_cast<Interface*>(new Derived());
auto b = static_cast<Interface*>(a);
```

When a `virtual` method is called via an object pointer, the compiler dereferences the object pointer to access a hidden pointer to a vtable belonging to the type that the object pointer is pointing at, and then it indexes into that vtable to know which class method to call.

The `Derived` object looks something like this in memory (details may vary by compiler, but this is the gist of it <sup>1</sup>):

```
                       +-------+
                   +-> | ~Base |--> &Derived::~Derived()
                   |   | func1 |--> &Derived::func1()
+---------------+  |   | func3 |--> &Derived::func3()
|   Base vmt    |--+   +-------+
|---------------|        +------------+
| Interface vmt |------> | ~Interface |--> &Derived::~Derived()
|---------------|        | func2      |--> &Derived::func2()
|  Derived vmt  |--+     +------------+
+---------------+  |   +------------+
                   +-> | ~Base      |--> &Derived::~Derived()
                       | func1      |--> &Derived::func1()
                       | func3      |--> &Derived::func3()
                       | ~Interface |--> &Derived::~Derived()
                       | func2      |--> &Derived::func2()
                       | ~Derived   |--> &Derived::~Derived()
                       +------------+
```

A `Derived` object consists of everything in `Base`, `Interface` and `Derived` cobbled together.  Each class still has its own pointer to a virtual method table belonging to that class.  But since `Derived` implements all of the `virtual` methods, a `Derived` object has multiple vtable pointers, and they all refer to `Derived`'s methods.

<sup>1: for efficiency, it is likely that `Derived` only has 1 vtable and all 3 of its vmt pointers are pointing to different areas of that single table.  But that is an implementation detail, not important for purposes of this answer.</sup>

When `a` is declared as `Interface*`, it points at the `Interface` portion of the `Derived` object:

```
     +---------------+
     |   Base vmt    |
     |---------------|
a -> | Interface vmt |
     |---------------|
     |  Derived vmt  |
     +---------------+
```

Type-casting `a` to `Interface*` is effectively a no-op, resulting in `b` being an `Interface*` pointer to the `Interface` portion of the `Derived` object:

```
     +---------------+
     |   Base vmt    |
     |---------------|
b -> | Interface vmt |
     |---------------|
     |  Derived vmt  |
     +---------------+
```

So calling `b->func2()` uses `Interface'`s vtable, jumping to 2nd entry which is `Derived::func2()`, as expected.

When `a` is declared as `Base*`, it points at the `Base` portion of the `Derived` object:

```
     +---------------+
a -> |   Base vmt    |
     |---------------|
     | Interface vmt |
     |---------------|
     |  Derived vmt  |
     +---------------+
```

But type-casting `a` to `Interface*` is **Undefined Behavior**, because `Base` and `Interface` are not related to each other, resulting in `b` being an `Interface*` pointer to the `Base` portion of the `Derived` object:

```
     +---------------+
b -> |   Base vmt    |
     |---------------|
     | Interface vmt |
     |---------------|
     |  Derived vmt  |
     +---------------+
```

So calling `b->func2()` mistakenly uses `Base`'s vtable instead of `Interface`'s vtable, jumping to the 2nd entry which is `Derived::func1()`, unexpectedly.

Had you used `static_cast` instead of a C-style cast here, the compile would have simply failed instead (this is why you should avoid using C-style casts in C++!).

When `a` is declared as `Derived*`, it points at the `Derived` portion of the `Derived` object:

```
     +---------------+
     |   Base vmt    |
     |---------------|
     | Interface vmt |
     |---------------|
a -> |  Derived vmt  |
     +---------------+
```

Type-casting `a` to `Interface*` is well-defined since `Interface` is a base of `Derived`, resulting in `b` being an `Interface*` pointer to the `Interface` portion of the `Derived` object:

```
     +---------------+
     |   Base vmt    |
     |---------------|
b -> | Interface vmt |
     |---------------|
     |  Derived vmt  |
     +---------------+
```

So calling `b->func2()` uses `Interface`'s vtable, jumping to the 2nd entry which is `Derived::func2()`, as expected.

When `a` is declared as `void*`, it points at the `Derived` portion of the `Derived` object:

```
     +---------------+
     |   Base vmt    |
     |---------------|
     | Interface vmt |
     |---------------|
a -> |  Derived vmt  |
     +---------------+
```

But type-casting `a` to `Interface*` is **Undefined Behavior**, because `a` is not pointing at the `Interface` portion of the `Derived` object, resulting in an `Interface*` pointer to the `Derived` portion of the `Derived` object:

```
     +---------------+
     |   Base vmt    |
     |---------------|
     | Interface vmt |
     |---------------|
b -> |  Derived vmt  |
     +---------------+
```

So calling `b->func2()` mistakenly uses `Derived`'s vtable instead of `Interface`'s vtable, jumping to the 2nd entry which is `Derived::func1()`, unexpectedly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

May I ask another question?

Then, does a pointer have a virtual table pointer?

Why does a pointer lose the original virtual table information?

Comment: I really appreciated it, Remy. Of course I have considered using c++ style cast, but it is not an option for my cases. I should use DWORD*. By the way, I found that when Derived class inherits Base and Interface orderly, an address of b should be a 8 byte later than that of a. I wonder this kind of operation is a 'defined' behavior.
And finally, void* a = (Interface*)(new Derived()); auto b = (Interface*)a; works well. Is it proper way?

Comment: And finally, void* a = (Interface*)(new Derived()); auto b = (Interface*)a; works well. Is it proper way? <- 
Sorry for this question... I know this is right way. Would you answer the first question only?

Answer (score 0):

Behaviour is undefined, since you are not converting a `void *` back to the actual type.

You either need to do

```
 void *a = (Interface*)(new Derived());
 auto b = (Interface *)a;
```

or add an extra step between your two

```
void* a = new Derived();     
auto temp = (Derived *)a;     // explicitly convert the void pointer to the actual type
auto b = (Interface*)temp;
```

which is equivalent to

```
void* a = new Derived();     
auto b = (Interface*)((Derived *)a);
```

Either way, without the conversion of the `void *` to `Derived *` before converting to `Interface *`, the behaviour is undefined.

Consider using one of the `_cast`s (e.g. `static_cast`) for conversion instead of C-style casts as well.